# Strsplit() by second occurence of the delimiter

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to split by the second occurrence of a character in a string (return substring in string before second appearance of character `x`)

For the string:

`s <-"a_b_c"` , if delimiter is `"_"` , I need  the substring : `"a_b"`

My function returns the substring by first occurence:

```
 return_topic<-function(s)
 {
   if (length(grep("_",s))>0)
     { return (unlist(strsplit(s,"_"))[1])}
    else return  (" ")

  }


> return_topic("a_b_c")
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Don't know if it would be the easiest way, but why not split by the delimiter and then add the first to back together by the same delimiter.
v=strsplit(word,split=”|”,fixed=TRUE)

Comment: What characteristics do a, b and c have? Are they always the same length?

Comment: a,b,c are strings of any length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub("(.*?_.*?)_.*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "a_b"
```

Comment: or you might want to write it as `pat <- "(.*?_.*?)_(.*)"; sub(pat, "\\1", s)` since then `sub(pat, "\\2", s)` gives the second half of the split.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `strsplit`

```
s <- c('a_b_c', '_b', '_bc_', 'abc__')
sapply(strsplit(s, '^[^_]*?[_][^_]*?(*SKIP)(*F)|_', perl=TRUE),`[`,1)
#[1] "a_b"  "_b"   "_bc"  "abc_"
```